# trying to install hs-ffmpeg haskell package fails to find libdc1394

Tags: haskell, ffmpeg

doing "cabal install hs-ffmpeg" fails like this:

```
checking for faacEncGetVersion in -lfaac... no
checking for zlibVersion in -lz... yes
checking for libdc1394... configure: error: Package requirements (libdc1394) were not met:

No package 'libdc1394' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libdc1394_CFLAGS
and libdc1394_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hs-ffmpeg-0.3.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
exit: ExitFailure 1
```

I have libdc1394-22 and libdc1394-22-dev installed on Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala.
I'm thinking that the dependency needs to be updated to reflect the new package that supercedes libdc1394, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hs-ffmpeg's `configure` script is looking for a `libdc1394.pc`.  For some reason, Ubuntu ships a `libdc1394-2.pc` instead.

Edit hs-ffmpeg's `configure.ac` to use the "correct" name and then run `autoreconf`, and it should work.

Something like `mkdir -p ~/.pc; ln -s /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libdc1394-2.pc ~/.pc/libdc1394.pc; export PKG_CONFIG_PATH+=:~/.pc` may work too.